# Upgrade Ubuntu 20 to 22 fail kernel install

Tags: upgrade, kernel, initramfs

I completed the upgrade from Ubuntu 20 to 22 and it failed to boot due to a kernel panic. I booted to an old kernel and found that the kernel was not installing properly.

```
Setting up linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic (5.15.0-67.74) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic (5.15.0-67.74) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-67-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-67-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/yellow_carp_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_sdma1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
cpio: write error: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 2
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-67-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is confusing since /boot has lots of space:

```
sudo df -h /boot
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc2       916G  160G  717G  19% /
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to help?

Comment: Do you have a separate `/boot` partition?  Run `sudo df -h` without any arguments like paths, etc. to let us see *all* mounted partitions.  What you ran shows only I believe your standard root partition and not the boot partition, I highly doubt you have a 1TB boot partition.

Comment: /boot is not separate, it is part of /

Comment: Please add `df -h;df -i`  and `dkms status` If command dkms is not found forget about that.